# "Простуживаться" или "простужаться"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Люди употребляют и тот, и тот вариант. Но "простужаться" — это вообще неправильно или есть такое слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По словарю Кузнецова — варианты равноправны. Причем оба несвободны (т.е. правильны, но вызывают затруднения при употреблении и восприятии).

А почему вы сочли сомнительным именно "простужаться"?
Мне "на слух" этот вариант куда более приятен. Тогда как "простуживаться" производит впечатление надуманного.